# ASP.Net web api: logging middleware: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, exception, logging, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to implement request-response logging middleware in asp.net core web API application. It's working as fine in normal flow. But on an exception in the application, seeing ObjectDisposed error

*System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.*
Here are the code blocks:

```
public class LoggingMiddleware
{
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddlewarecs> _logger;

        public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate requestDelegate, ILogger<LoggingMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = requestDelegate;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
            var body = await new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation($"Body: {body}");
            httpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            //await _next(context);
            var originalBodyStream = httpContext.Response.Body;
            using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var response = httpContext.Response;

                response.Body = responseBody;
                
                await _next(httpContext);                

                string responseBodyContent = null;
                responseBodyContent = await ReadResponseBody(response);
                await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
                _logger.LogInformation(responseBodyContent);
            }
        } 
}
```

**In Startup.cs Configiration method**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {                
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error-developer");                
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");               
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            
            app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddlewarecs>();

            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
}
```

**Error Controller**

```
public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
{
        [Route("/error-developer")]
        public IActionResult Error([FromServices] IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            var ex = context?.Error;
            var isDev = webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment();

            return Problem(
                detail: context.Error.StackTrace,
                title: context.Error.Message);
        }

        [Route("/error")]
        public IActionResult Error() => Problem();
}
```

Exception throwing at **await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);**

Any thoughts/ideas, please?
Or any better way of implementing request-response logging and exception handling?

Comment: You forgot to mention where the code is thrown. The reason is clear - the code tried to use a Stream after it was closed. Perhaps the middleware is trying to access the Body stream *after* it was closed by some other call? Or the middleware runs *before* the middleware component that handles request object lifetimes?

Comment: BTW at least the exception handling middleware is trying to reinvent what ASP.NET Core already does. In development, the rich information screen shown by ASP.NET Core is a lot better than just an exception's text. In production, sending the full exception to the client is a *MAJOR* security problem, as it exposes the code's internals and methods.  If you want to customize what gets returned, ASP.NET Core offers extension points and custom error pages already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for comments. Question updated with exception details. Right, it tried access the stream stream after closing it. But, couldn't figure it out how or where to fix it.  Let's say, I am trying to throw custom exceptions and need to catch them at gobally and it's only web api application and not UI. I can use action filters, but trying with middleware, unless it's completely not a recommended approach use exception logging middleware.

Comment: The point is that ASP.NET Core *already* provides such middleware. That's what `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` is for. There's an exception handler page already for production environments. This is described in the docs, in [Handle Errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The article shows how to customize this, and leads to [exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#exception-filters) to handle exceptions globally

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos even with the default error handling, I am getting the same error on exception. While accessing the response stream in middleware, it's throwing error.